How use title from generateMetadata() in UI in NextJs 14?
I use generateMetadata() like this
export async function generateMetadata(
  { params, searchParams }: Props,
  parent: ResolvingMetadata
): Promise<Metadata> {
  
  const slug = params.slug
 
  const product = await fetch(...).then((res) => res.json())
  return {
    title: product.title,
  }
}

it works great, but i want use the title from generateMetadata() in UI, how can i do this without a new request?

What do you mean by setting the title in UI?

I want use title like h1 {title}

As mentioned in the comments, you want to use the data of the generateMetadata in the UI itself.
The official recommendation is to fetch the data where it is needed.
async function getData(slug) {
  return fetch(....).then(res => res.json())
}

export async generateMetadata({ params }) {
  const data = await getData(params.slug);

  return { title: data.title }
}

export default async function Page({ params }) {
  const data = await getData(params.slug);

  return <h1>{data.title}</h1>
}

While this might look like duplicate requests. It is NOT.

React extends the fetch API to automatically memoize requests that have the same URL and options. This means you can call a fetch function for the same data in multiple places in a React component tree while only executing it once.

For example, if you need to use the same data across a route (e.g. in a Layout, Page, and multiple components), you do not have to fetch data at the top of the tree, and forward props between components. Instead, you can fetch data in the components that need it without worrying about the performance implications of making multiple requests across the network for the same data.
Good to know:
Request memoization is a React feature, not a Next.js feature. (...)
Memoization only applies to the GET method in fetch requests.
Memoization only applies to the React Component tree, this means:

It applies to fetch requests in generateMetadata, `generateStaticParams, Layouts, Pages, and other Server Components.


Documentation
